# Extract unique string elements from dataframe column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe containing two columns:

- an `id`
- `string`: which is a text string column, containing repeated text elements separated by the symbols `/`

  ```
  library(tidyverse)

  df_input <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                      id = c(123, 234, 345, 456),
                  string = c("[\"aaa\"] / [\"aaa\"] / [\"aaa\"] / bbb / bbb / bbb",
                             "[\"hello hello\"] / [\"hello hello\"] / [\"hello hello\"] / [\"hello hello\"]",
                             "my name is tim / my name is tim / my name is tim", "[\"hello word\"]")
            )
  ```

Looking like:

```
       id                                                                string
     1 123                         ["aaa"] / ["aaa"] / ["aaa"] / bbb / bbb / bbb
     2 234 ["hello hello"] / ["hello hello"] / ["hello hello"] / ["hello hello"]
     3 345                      my name is tim / my name is tim / my name is Tim
     4 456                                                        ["hello word"]
```

The pattern I see is that each time there is a group of repeated elements, it is separated by the symbol `/`:

```
["aaa"] / ["aaa"] / ["aaa"] / bbb / bbb / bbb
```

Or:

```
my name is tim / my name is tim / my name is Tim
```

But also cases with a single element:

```
["hello word"]
```

I would like to have a dataframe like the following:

```
df_output <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                       id = c(123, 234, 345, 456),
                   string = c("[\"aaa\"] / bbb", "[\"hello hello\"]", "my name is tim",
                              "[\"hello word\"]")
             )
```

Where:

```
   id          string
1 123   ["aaa"] / bbb
2 234 ["hello hello"]
3 345  my name is tim
4 456  ["hello word"]
```

and I keep only the unique elements; if multiple elements are present, they are separated by `/`.

Any solution in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 2):

Using stringr's `str_split` and purrr to `map` the unique finding and recombining:

```r
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_input %>%
  mutate(string = string %>% 
           str_split(" / ") %>%
           map(unique) %>%
           map_chr(paste, collapse = " / "))
#>    id          string
#> 1 123   ["aaa"] / bbb
#> 2 234 ["hello hello"]
#> 3 345  my name is tim
#> 4 456  ["hello word"]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```r
df_input %>%
  separate_rows(string, sep=" / ") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(string = paste(string, collapse=" / "), .groups="drop") %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

returns

```r
   id          string
1 123   ["aaa"] / bbb
2 234 ["hello hello"]
3 345  my name is tim
4 456  ["hello word"]
```

The `group_by`, `summarise` and `as.data.frame` part can be skipped with

```r
aggregate(string ~ id, ., paste, collapse=" / ")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `cSplit` and `data.table`

```
library(splitstackshape)
unique(cSplit(df_input, "string", sep= " / ", "long"))[,
       .(string = paste(string, collapse= " / ")),.(id)]
#   id          string
#1: 123   ["aaa"] / bbb
#2: 234 ["hello hello"]
#3: 345  my name is tim
#4: 456  ["hello word"]
```